Unable to import WTForm class from one file to another
I am unable to import NamerForm from forms.py to controllers.py. Getting ImportError
ImportError: cannot import NamerForm from application.forms
File Directory structure:
.venv
|____applications
   |-__init__.py
   |-config.py
   |-controllers.py
   |-forms.py
|____templates
   |-name.html
|____static
|____main.py

main.py
from flask import Flask
import os, application.config
from application.config import LocalDevelopmentConfig
from application.database import db


app = None

def create_app():
     app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')
     app.config['SECRET_KEY']='somekey'
     if os.getenv('ENV',"development") == "production":
          raise Exception("Currently no production config is set up.")
     else:
          print("Starting Local Development")
          app.config.from_object(LocalDevelopmentConfig)
     db.init_app(app)
     app.app_context().push()

     return(app)

app = create_app()


from application.controllers import *
if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)

forms.py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class NamerForm(FlaskForm):
     name = StringField("write something", validators=[DataRequired()])
     submit = SubmitField("Submit")

controllers.py
from flask import Flask,render_template, url_for
from flask import current_app as app
#from app import app
from .forms import NamerForm

#---other app routes--------

@app.route("/name", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def name():
     name = None
     form = NamerForm()
     if form.validate_on_submit():
         name = form.name.data
         form.name.data = ''
     return(render_template("name.html", name = name, form = form))

Note that without 'name' function the app is running error free.

I think from applications.forms import NamerForm instead of from .forms import NamerForm resolves the issue.

@vit still same error.
ImportError: cannot import 'NamerForm' from 'application.forms' (C:\users\path\to\forms.py)

You should rename your folder or change the import name to applications. However, renaming the folder is a better approach since the correct folder name is application or app according to Flask patterns.
I tested your code by changing the folder name, and it works.

1.Could you once verify if my directory structure of my project is correct? like i have made every directory inside my (.venv)
2.Also vscode is running the code only when i am hitting the play button. otherwise if i am using flask run or python3 .venv\main.py it is not working.

Try to execute cd .venv/ and then python3 main.py (and you should rename the folder too as I said in the answer). It's not common execute the code outside root directory.
